# Xcode 13 Swiftui change dynamically value of a variable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, mapbox

I have a Boolean variables called `points`. The initial value of points is setted to `false` because I want a certain behaviour. Then in a function I want to change the value of the `points` variable to `true`.

I read some documentation about swift (because I'm new) but I'm not getting why the value of `points` is not changing.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapboxMaps
import MapboxCoreMaps
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

struct MapBoxView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MapViewController {
        return MapViewController()
    }
      
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MapViewController, context: Context) {}
}

@objc(MapViewController)

public class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    internal var mapView: MapView!
    private let customImage = UIImage(named: "location-pin-1")!
    var n: Int = 0

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50, longitude: 10)
        
        let options = MapInitOptions(cameraOptions: CameraOptions(center: centerCoordinate, zoom: 2.4))

        mapView = MapView(frame: view.bounds, mapInitOptions: options)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        mapView.mapboxMap.onNext(.mapLoaded) { _ in
            self.setupExample()
        }
    }

    public func setupExample() {
        addTapGesture(to: mapView)
    }

    public func addTapGesture(to mapView: MapView) {
        self.n = self.n + 1
        if (self.n < 2) {
            let tapGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(addPoint))
            mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        }
    }

    @objc public func addPoint(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapPoint = sender.location(in: mapView)
        
        let coordinate = mapView.mapboxMap.coordinate(for: tapPoint)
        
        let pointAnnotationManager = mapView.annotations.makePointAnnotationManager()
        
        var customPointAnnotation = PointAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate)
        
        customPointAnnotation.image = .init(image: customImage, name: "my-custom-image-name")
        pointAnnotationManager.annotations = [customPointAnnotation]
    
    }
    
}
```

This all is included in a class that use `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not SwiftUI, so remove the `@State` property wrapper, make it just  `var points: Bool = false`

If you are using `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `UIViewController` then you are using `UIKit` not `SwiftUI`

Comment: Yes. Sorry this is `UIKit` but just because I wrapped it in a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

But removing the `@State` doesn't change anything. My variable is still not updating.

Comment: Can you include more of your code (the parts where addTapGesture is called) and how do you know that the variable isn't changing its value

Comment: I updated the code. As you can see I'm using `mapbox` and I want that the user can add at most 2 points. But `n` is not updating since when I run the app I can add how many marker I want.